# Backwards hierarchy in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table (ok, it's a CTE) that I need to pull the hierarchy out of, except instead of parent_id, I have child-id...

eg

```
Rule_ID | Group_Name | Function_ID | Info    | Child_ID
1         'ABC'        1             '1blah'   0
1         'ABC'        2             '2blah'   3
2         'ABC'        5             '5blah'   0
2         'ABC'        6             '6blah'   7
null      'ABC'        7             '7blah'   11
null      'ABC'        11            '11blah'  0
```

Now the other problem is that the function_id is unique as part of the group, and a Rule_id will not appear on the child, and this is nth level. ie, while Function_ID = 3 exists, it doesn't have the same Rule_ID.

What I need is:

```
Rule_ID | Group_Name | Function_ID | Info  
1         'ABC'        1             '1blah'
1         'ABC'        2             '2blah'
1         'ABC'        3             '3blah'
2         'ABC'        5             '5blah'
2         'ABC'        6             '6blah'
2         'ABC'        7             '7blah'
2         'ABC'        11            '11blah'
```

I've tried the standard hierarchy functions, but they all seem to work based on Parent_ID, not Child_ID.

Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: This is not clear. In the "desired" output you have a row where Info is '3blah'. There is no such value in the Info column in your inputs. Where did that value come from? Then: what you describe below your inputs is clear as mud (at least to me) - what do you mean? Why does all that matter? I am sure it does, but you didn't explain how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you need, although I'm pretty sure there is a less clunky way of doing it...

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 1 function_id, '1blah' info, 0 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 2 function_id, '2blah' info, 3 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 5 function_id, '5blah' info, 0 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 6 function_id, '6blah' info, 7 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT NULL rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 3 function_id, '3blah' info, 0 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT NULL rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 7 function_id, '7blah' info, 11 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT NULL rule_id, 'ABC' group_name, 11 function_id, '11blah' info, 0 child_id FROM dual)
SELECT sd1.rule_id,
       sd1.group_name,
       sd1.function_id,
       (SELECT info FROM sample_data sd2 WHERE sd2.function_id = sd1.function_id) info
FROM   (SELECT rule_id,
               group_name,
               connect_by_root(function_id) function_id,
               connect_by_isleaf isleaf 
        FROM   sample_data sd
        CONNECT BY PRIOR function_id = child_id
                   AND PRIOR group_name = group_name) sd1
WHERE  isleaf = 1
ORDER BY rule_id, function_id;

   RULE_ID GROUP_NAME FUNCTION_ID INFO
---------- ---------- ----------- ------
         1 ABC                  1 1blah
         1 ABC                  2 2blah
         1 ABC                  3 3blah
         2 ABC                  5 5blah
         2 ABC                  6 6blah
         2 ABC                  7 7blah
         2 ABC                 11 11blah
```

Remember: just because a column is labelled "child_id" doesn't mean it can't be a parent id... you've just got to relabel things in your head

Comment: Did you make an educated guess that the OP meant to have the fifth row in your sample_data (the first row with NULL rule_d) in his/her inputs? I don't see it there.

Comment: Yes, based on what the OP said: `ie, while Function_ID = 3 exists, it doesn't have the same Rule_ID`

Comment: Perfect. Like you said, @Boneist, I was hung up on the logic of it.